# How to center a div above another div all the time

Tags: html, css

This scenario is somewhat different than the traditional margin:0 auto.

I try to center a div above another div, while both of them are in the same div (no need to look like they are in the same div, because blue box will be bigger than black box on top)!

I have create a fiddle of what I got so far, and I did align the top div into sort center, but its center in a sense of top left corner of each div. I want to center in a sense that, the blue box is RIGHT above the blackbox, but the bluebox's middle line is aligned with the middleline of the blackbox. So something like this

```
 |______|

   |__|
```

***top box blue, bottom box black***

But I just can't think of a way to do that.

http://jsfiddle.net/adamchenwei/nay8fe5q/

HTML

```
<div class="blockcontainer">
    <div class="blockcenterbox">
        <div class="blocktop">abc</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blockbottom"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.blockcontainer {

    margin:0 auto;

    width:25px;

    background-color:#00CC66;

}

.blocktop {

    width:100px;

    background-color:#6699FF;

    height:50px;

}

.blockcenterbox {

    width: .1px;

    height: 5px;

    background-color: yellow;

    margin: 0 auto;

    position: relative;

    float: none;

}

.blockbottom {

    width:25px;

    height:25px;

    background-color:black;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

```css
.blue {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.black {
    width: 150px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.blockcontainer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blockcontainer">
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="black"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hum... sorta! I wonder if the blackbox is a actual image.. will that still work the same way?

Comment: Assuming the `.black` `div` is replaced with an `img` tag, you need to add `display: block;` to the `.black` CSS to center the image

Comment: Should work fine with an image within that top div .. see jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/f19fjhu8/

Comment: @Silvertiger ah, the demo has a little mistake, the image should be on the black one :)

Comment: Same concept .. put an image into the black the same way ... http://jsfiddle.net/y96pzy7m/

Answer (score 0):

Try this working link at plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/OaQBWxlIfa2fVvanKKEl?p=preview

Hope it helps!!!
HTML

```
<div class="blockcontainer">
    <div class="blockcenterbox">
        <div class="blocktop">abc</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blockbottom"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.blockcontainer {
            width:200px;
        height:200px;
            background-color:#00CC66;
        overflow:hidden;

        }

        .blocktop {
            width:100px;
            background-color:#6699FF;
            height:50px;

        }

        .blockcenterbox {
            width: 100px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: yellow;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .blockbottom {
            width:25px;
            height:25px;
            background-color:black;
        margin: 0 auto;
        }
```